# Disable List of Checkboxes with razor

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have the following code to render rows of checkboxes

```
<div id="notificationSettings">
    @for (var itr = 0; itr < Model.Item1.Settings.Length; itr++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group text-center">
            <p>@Model.Item1.Settings[itr].Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group text-center">
            <input asp-for="Item1.Settings[itr].Notify" type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Settings[itr].Notify" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group text-center">
            <input asp-for="Item1.Settings[itr].ByEmail" type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Settings[itr].ByEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 form-group text-center">
            <input asp-for="Item1.Settings[itr].BySms" type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Settings[itr].BySms" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

if I want to disable `ByEmail` and `BySms` checkboxes if `Notify` checkbox is unchecked then I can do something like this for a single set of checkbox :

```
document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_0__Notify").addEventListener('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_0__ByEmail").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_0__BySms").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_0__ByEmail").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_0__BySms").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

My question is can I have one event handler which can handle any N number of checkboxes that only differ in `Id`. Or do I need N number of event handlers? If that be the case how can I register N number of event handlers with a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know about [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in javascript, the following should work:

```
function handleCheckbox(i) {
    document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__Notify").addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__ByEmail").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__BySms").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__ByEmail").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__BySms").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__ByEmail").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("Item1_Settings_" + i + "__BySms").checked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

And then this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Item1.Settings.Length; i++) {
    handleCheckbox(i);
}
```

Also, would be nice if you renamed your ids better :)